# EF Core database-first identity column issue

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I am using EF Core 3.1 with a database-first approach using Linq-to-Entities to add a new entity, but I get the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table XXX when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I generated the tables automatically so the ID column type is int and set by default to 0.and I cannot set it to NULL because it is not Nullable.

I don't want to explicitly set value, I just want it to auto increase as it should.

Here is my code:

```
Person person =new Person()
{
     FirstName="Dan",
     Age=22
};
db.Persons.Add(person);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Class Person (generated from db):

```
public partial class Person
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Thank in advance for any help

Comment: `I generated the tables automatically` what does that mean? You didn't post any code that makes `ID` an `IDENTITY`, so how did it become one?

Comment: I generated them by running Scaffold-DbContext...
and i set the ID to be identity in my database

Comment: if the column already had the `IDENTITY` attribute, Scaffold should have emitted the FluentAPI code *at least*. If you used the -`DataAnnotations` parameter, it should have emitted the attributes too. What does your DbContext configuration code look like?

Comment: If you set `IDENTITY` *after* scaffolding though, you need to regenerate the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell EF Core that `ID` is [generated by the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations). One way to do this is with the [DatabaseGenerated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute, eg :

```
public partial class Person
{
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` option tells EF Core that the database generates new values when a record is inserted. Without this, EF Core would include the value of the `ID` property in the `INSERT` command

Comment: doesn't it mean that every time I update my tables schema from the db I will have to that again?

Comment: @chana the code generation step should have added that attribute in the first place. Either that, or add the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd();` call in the DbContext's configuration. How did you generate those classes? What does the DbContext's code look like?

Comment: I generated those classes by running 'Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxxx;Database=xxx;User Id=xxx; Password=xxx" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models' in my pm console

Answer (score 2):

You should add the next attributes to your class definition:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
....
public partial class Person
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The [Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute denotes the field should be a primary key, 
and the [DatabaseGenerated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute tells about key generation way.

Comment: @Miamy- doesn't it mean that every time I update my tables schema from the db I will have to that again?

Comment: At least you should check if these lines are present in generated file. I think, theoretically EF core can add them automatically based on the db metadata, but for the moment it doesn't do it, (as I know).